# How do you vertically center text with an image in a LaTeX table?

Tags: image, alignment, latex, tabular

I want to align text with the center of a large image in LaTeX. Unfortunately, the text `some text` is aligned with the bottom of the image:

```
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    some text & \includegraphics{image_name.eps}
\end{tabular}
```

I've found a website that recommends using `m{width of the cell}` instead of `c` for that column in the table, but it hasn't worked.

```
\begin{tabular}{m{1in}c}
    some text & \includegraphics{image_name.eps}
\end{tabular}
```

I'm sure a latex pro would look at this and know what to do! Which implies that I cannot be a LaTeX pro until you teach me...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use minipages to align your text with the image:

```
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.25\textwidth}
Text comes here
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.25\textwidth}
\includegraphics{image_name.eps}
\end{minipage}
```

It´s not really a table, and you must specify the width of the minipages, but it may work for you.

Comment: Ah, good thinking! I found that using minipage to wrap images within a tabular makes everything work fine!

Comment: Thanks @Emilio. Just a note: personally here I had to additionally specify `[width=\textwidth]` on the `\includegraphics` command to make it actually fit the size of the minipage.